how to force a maximum map extent for geonode docker?
I’m running geonode docker, how do I need to modify the .env file to force a maximum map extent (e.g. Italy)?
This is my local installation procedure using the default .env

git clone -b 4.0.2 https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode.git
cd .\geonode\
docker compose build
docker compose up -d

I modify the .env and run docker compose down and docker compose up -d (https://docs.geonode.org/en/master/install/basic/index.html#customize-env-to-match-your-needs)

ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin4 # works and takes effect

DEFAULT_MAP_ZOOM=10 # works and takes effect

DEFAULT_MAP_CENTER_X=50 # does not work (if this does not work how can max force extent work)

DEFAULT_MAP_CENTER=50 # does not work


What are variable names and how to use them to force a maximum map extent ?

Setting the variables:
DEFAULT_MAP_CENTER_X = 1250000
DEFAULT_MAP_CENTER_Y = 5370000
DEFAULT_MAP_ZOOM = 8

will give me the following extent:

I also saw this map config under /static/mapstore/configs/map.json:
{
    "version": 2,
    "map": {
        "projection": "EPSG:900913",
        "units": "m",
        "center": {
            "x": 1250000.000000,
            "y": 5370000.000000,
            "crs": "EPSG:900913"
        },
        "zoom": 5,
        "maxExtent": [
            -20037508.34,
            -20037508.34,
            20037508.34,
            20037508.34
        ],
        "layers": []
    }
}

This did not had the desired effect during testing, though.
So it seems that you'd have to check why your settings do not apply appropriately.

thank u for guidance on defining the DEFAULT_MAP_CENTER // i found this regarding the forced max extent https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/extent-constrained.html do u know where to put for geonode/docker https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode/releases and how to make changes take effect ?

You can check the map config (here for the dataset_preview) in the localConfig. Try to add a View config. I cannot test it right now. If this works I would appreciate your feedback.

this seems to work - i was hoping to solver via .env but this seems to be the only reliable options however is tideous https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/geofence-server/index.html
